# Removing certain files from Drive folder based on name

Tags: google-drive

I have about 600 photos in a shared Drive folder. However, my camera uploaded both the ".RW2" files and the ".JPG" files, so I have a double of each photo. I want to delete all of the .RW2 files in the folder, but can't seem to find a way to do it without removing each file individually. Is there some sort of automated process I can use to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could write a script for this, but with 600 files, it seems easier to use the interface:

1. Search for `.RW2` using the search bar on top of screen: 
   [image]
2. Scroll down in the list of search result so that it loads more... and more... and more...
3. Press Ctrl-A or its Mac equivalent to select all these items.
4. Click on the trash icon to move them to trash.

Step 2 can be slightly annoying with many files. Drive uses infinite-scroll layout instead of fixed-size pagination of Gmail. It also lacks Gmail's capability to select all search results, even those not shown on the page. But still, the process is manageable and takes less time than writing an Apps Script and then worrying about whether it deleted the right things.

Comment: When I push Ctrl-A, ALL of the files are selected, not just the RW2 ones.

Comment: Did you skip step 1? After step 1, you should only see .RW2 files. I just tested this in my folder by pressing Ctrl-A and deleting files: the ones that don't match the string are not shown, not selected, and not deleting.

Comment: I might be confused on how to search in Drive. Right now I'm just using Ctrl-F to search for rw2 files

Comment: There's a search bar for that; I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Google Drive downloaded to your computer, you could use either 1) Windows's search function by searching "*.rw2". then pressing Ctrl+A and Del.
2) A command line to delete all files in the Google Drive Photos directory with the .rw2 ending. <

`del /s /q /f c:\.Users\...\Google Drive Photos\*.rw2`

Answer (score -2):

I know two lovely programs that can help with this problem.  File Locator Lite and Auslogics' Duplicate File Finder.

Comment: Those would only be effective if OP syncs all of the images to a computer; the programs you mentioned only work on offline files.